# access denied on cloud control app push git bash for windows

Tags: cloudcontrol

I am trying to push Piwigo CMS(http://piwigo.org/) to Cloudcontrol I tried the method as same as Drupal, which is described in https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Guides/PHP/Drupal%207 But I am getting this error
[image]

Comment: Please make sure you've setup your user account correctly. Especially the part about the public key: https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Quickstart

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed, as pst pointed out, a pubkey issue.
You might want to check your ssh config, it helped to define the following in my ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host cloudcontrolled.com
    user USERNAME
    IdentityFile ~/PATH_TO_YOUR/rsa_key
```

I dunno if this works as well in cygwin or similar: it would help if you could specify your environment a little bit more, as there are many elements (read binaries, configs, etc) in play here.